# Reference Request: Companion to Munkres' Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, self-learning

I am currently self studying multivariable calculus from Munkres' *Analysis on Manifolds*. However, I find most of the exercises in Munkres easy, and although they help me internalize the topics covered in the preceding section, I would really like a source for a number of harder problems. I have already browsed through several similar queries on this site, but I have not been able to find any answers that suit my needs. I would appreciate some advice on where I can find such problems.

Comment: Most calculus-type analysis is really boring. The only important concepts you learn are point-set topology concepts, which you could more efficiently study from a book like Munkres's topology. Analysis doesn't get useful at all until measure theory.

Comment: Well, if that is true, we should delete or close about 10% of the posts on StackExchange.

Comment: Measure theory is measurably more interesting?